# Use scoring function used by GridSearchCV to get predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am creating dynamic pipelines in scikit-learn and I set the scoring function as a parameter string on the `GridSearchCV`:

`gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, scoring='accuracy')`

However, when I try to get the scoring function that was used in order to evaluate the predictions, this is what I get:

```
  File "app/experimenter/sklearn/sklearn-dask-tests.py", line 127, in run_pipeline
    print(evaluator(expected, predicted))
TypeError: __call__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

This is the code:

```
gs.fit(train_data, train_target)

predicted = gs.predict(test_data)

evaluator = gs.scorer_

print(evaluator(expected, predicted))
```

So from what I have seen the problem is that the evaluator is in fact `make_scorer(accuracy_score)`. I guess it would be possible to get `print(evaluator(expected, predicted))` to work if I add the estimator as the first parameter, but how do I get it properly from the pipeline?

Cause when I do `gs.best_estimator_` I get this:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('mapper', DataFrameMapper(default=False, df_out=False,
        features=[('Sex', LabelBinarizer(neg_label=0, pos_label=1, sparse_output=False))],
        sparse=False)), ('DecisionTree', DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=3,
            max_features=1, max_...      min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best'))])
```

Comment: Which version of scikit are you using? In the latest the upper TyperError should not come. Also its confusing, you want the gridSearch inside pipeline, or pipeline inside GridSearch. Looking at the first line, its latter. Then you should use `best_estimator_` on gridSearchCV object, not on pipeline object as you have done here. You should post your complete code and full stack trace of TypeError above?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @VivekKumar. I am using 0.18.1. Sorry, it's just that I used the same variable name since these parts are in different functions. I edited it so that it doesn't get confusing. The pipeline is actually inside the `GridSearchCV`, but when I print `best_estimator_`, it gives me the pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thats the desired behaviour of GridSearchCV. The pipeline object returned from the `gs.best_estimator_` is already fitted on the whole `train_data` with best parameters found in grid search.

You need to send that pipeline object into the `evaluator`. But your current usage of `evaluator` is wrong.

What the scorer_ from make_scorer does it takes the test data, make predictions on it and then calculate score by comparing it with actual data.

Hence, its signature is:

`scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)`

But you are trying to use it as:

```
evaluator(expected, predicted)
```

It will not work because:

1. It does not satisfy the signature of scorer
2. It needs the X data, not the predicted y data.

So, if you already have the actual and predicted values of the data, you can simply use the:

`accuracy_score(expected, predicted)`

If you want to use the `scorer_` (your `evaluator`), then you should not supply it the `predicted`, instead supply the `test_data` (from which the `predicted` is got)

```
evaluator(gs.best_estimator_, test_data, expected)
```

Comment: You mean not supply the expected? I did this and the error is gone, but when I print this `evaluator(gs.best_estimator_, test_data, predicted)` I get 1.0, which doesn't make sense...

Comment: @LarissaLeite Sorry, use the `expected` instead of `predicted`. I have changed the code.